# Conditional format Excel cell so it is really blank and doesn't appear in a chart

Tags: excel, charts

I want to plot a column of data, but if a cell is missing I don't want it to appear in the plot.  This works as expected if the cells contain numbers.

But if the cells to be plotted are instead set equal to other cells, then I'm not sure how to handle the blank cells.

If I use:

```
=A3
```

and if A3 is blank, then this cell will contain a 0.

If I use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",A3)
```

and if A3 is blank, then this cell will *appear* blank.  However the plot will add a point with a zero value.  This cell is treated differently by the chart than if it were actually blank.

How can I set this cell to be blank (i.e., equivalent to 'clear contents'), if A3 is blank, so that the chart will skip it?

Comment: Try `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),NA(),A3)` and if you don't want the `#NA` to show, use conditional formatting to format the font color same as the background, if the cell contains NA

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Unfortunately a chart will still pick that up as a point it needs to plot.

Comment: Provide examples of your data, the actual and desired outputs.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld actually, you are right, NA() works okay -- it's not plotted as a 0 like the "" is.  If you add it this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),NA(),A3)
```

and if you don't want the `#NA` to show, use conditional formatting to format the font color same as the background, if the cell contains NA